# How to fetch Token ID from Google Smart Home Skill to AWS

Tags: lambda, fetch, client, access-token

I want to fetch the `access_token` of the user client who logged into my Google Smart Home Skill.

I am trying it through AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda in Node JavaScript and done with OAuth 2.0.